# How to disable uiswitch in custom cell of uitableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiswitch

Hi I am working on UITableView and UISwitch. I have custom cells which contains UISwitches. At the beginning the UISwitch is off and I turn it on. When I turn on the UISwitch in another cell the UISwitch which was turned on in the beginning should turn off. I am implementing this in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

I am checking whether for particular symptoms remedyID is selected. If it is selected switch on and rest should be turned off. I am even releading the data.

```
cell.remedyID=[[[remedyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                              objectForKey:@"RemedyID"]intValue];

cell.symptomIDNo =[[[remedyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                  objectForKey:@"SymptomID"]intValue];

int checkValue = [[activeNotificationDictionary objectForKey:
                   [[remedyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] 
                          objectForKey:@"SymptomID"]]intValue];

if (cell.remedyID == checkValue){

    objdb.notifyMe.on = YES;
} else {

    objdb.notifyMe.on = NO;
}


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]){

        [activeNotificationDictionary setObject:
          [NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedRemedyID] forKey:
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:iPath]];

        [remedyTableView reloadData];
     }    
}
```

So if anyone can help me ..that would be great

Comment: What result are you getting with the code you posted?

Comment: when i turn on the second uiswitch ..i get an alertview when i click OK ..the first uiswitch isnt turning off .both switches remain ON . i can mail u .m file if  u want .u will get better idea

Comment: That would be helpful. You can send it to rdelmar@comcast.net

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a boolean in your data-array which provides the content for the uiTable to check, weather a switch is on or off.

When you trigger one switch, you save the index in a global variable of the class which is the tableview delegate. Then in the alertview you can use the saved index to manipulate the boolean value of the state of the switch in your data-array.
After that you reload the table.

Of course you have to change your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in that way, that the state of the switch is taken from the boolean value and not defaulted to off.

Answer (score 0):

I think your remedyArray contains remedy Objects. Those object should have a Boolean property and use that property for turning it on and off. When you turn one on go iterate and turn off other ones. If you cant add a BOOL property to your remedy class consider creating a an inherited class or class extension. 
Now that is one way. If you are too worried about memory use an instance variable to store the indexpath of the row that has switch on. and using that variable display the cells accordingly means with the switch on or off. When a new switch is selected simply call the reload data and  the table should draw properly.

Comment: Siby i have called reload data when new switch is selected .. i have called it in - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex